# How do I get IDirect3DDevice in Rust/WinRT?

Tags: rust, windows-runtime, directx

I wanted to capture a screen in a [`winrt-rs`](https://github.com/microsoft/winrt-rs) project, so followed [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture).

However, I didn't know how to get the first argument `IDirect3DDevice` of `Direct3D11CaptureFramePool.Create()`.

For C++/WinRT, there is a function to get the interface in `Windows.graphics.directx.direct3d11.interop.h`, but how do I do in Rust?

Comment: You have an example here: https://github.com/robmikh/wgc-rust-demo

Comment: It’s the very answer I was looking for. Many thanks.